# How do I make the terminal font a little brighter?

Tags: release-freya, fonts, pantheon-terminal

On my laptop the terminal font color is too dark. I need more contrast with the background.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the font color, you can use [Configurator](https://launchpad.net/configurator). Once you've installed the application, you go to `org.pantheon.terminal.settings` and change the value of `foreground` to any color you want. The default color in my system is `#94a3a5`

If you don't want to use Configurator(or dconf-editor) you an use terminal and paste this 
`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings foreground '#000'` and change `#000` with the color you want.

To restore the default color settings , paste this on your terminal 
`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings foreground '#94a3a5'`

Comment: The gsettings command does it very well. To properly chose the desired color,  [`gcolor2`](http://askubuntu.com/a/351470/47206) from the repos is useful.